# /etc/profile.d scripts apparently aren't executed at login

Tags: command-line, alias

Does `/etc/profile.d` work or not?

I create a file `rexster-console.sh` in `/etc/profile.d`:

```
alias rexster="/var/rexster-console-2.4.0/bin/rexster-console.sh"

-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    66 Feb 15 13:05 rexster-console.sh
```

I even run `sh rexster-console.sh`.

I open up another terminal:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/profile.d# rexster
rexster: command not found
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What you are missing?

The files from `/etc/profile.d` directory are sourced at startup, not when the application (in your case *another terminal*) starts. So, probably after a system restart your alias will work.

But, the right way to create aliases is:

- if you want to create system wide aliases, these should go in `/etc/bashrc` file
- if you want to create personal aliases, these should go into your `~/.bashrc` file, or better into `~/bash_aliases` file.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

This link says profile.d should also be loaded with new shell login.

Comment: At least on RHEL 7, a comment in /etc/bashrc reads:

"# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates."